# I'd sooner starve than eat that disgusting food. (sooner or rather)

Tags: idioms, idioms-in-context

> I'd sooner starve than eat that disgusting food.

> I'd rather starve than eat that disgusting food.

Why 'sooner' becomes 'rather'? Literally speaking, it's weird.

Comment: Are you asking why *sooner* means the same thing as *rather*?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's a weird thing because 'sooner' is a comparative form of 'soon'.

Comment: But *soon* means "close in time", so when we say "sooner" we are saying "closer in time", like "I would do X *before* I would do Y."

Comment: Is there nuance difference between them something like euphemism or anything to refer to?

Comment: Wait til you find "I'd as soon …" or even "I'd as soon a…" which is possibly dialectic. They're idioms. Once something becomes idiomatic, it survives other changes in the language. I would think 'sooner' is an older form than 'rather' but I have nothing but gut feel to back that up.

Comment: @DoneWithThis.: [Here you are.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27d+sooner+starve%2CI%27d+rather+starve&year_start=1790&year_end=1890&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) Back your gut feel up with that usage chart, showing that ***I'd sooner starve*** was much more common than ***I'd rather starve*** until the 1830s.

Comment: @gomadeng *It's a weird thing because 'sooner' is a comparative form of 'soon'.* "Rather" is also a comparative form, although its absolute form hasn't survived. [M-W says](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rather): "from Old English *hrathor*, comparative of *hrathe* quickly"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are two very different words, but in this context, they both amount to the same thing.

*I'd sooner starve - I am going to starve before I eat disgusting food.*

*I'd rather starve - I would prefer starvation to eating disgusting food.*

*Sooner* here means the speaker would do *thing* before doing *other thing*.

*Rather* is a direct comparison: in the choice of two options, I would do *thing* and not *other thing*

*I'd sooner . . .* is more old-fashioned.
*I'd rather . . .* is used more often now.

Comment: @LeLtter a minor one: not the other thing. (one, the other, if there are only two options)